# How does contact area affect the transmission of vibration from one object to another?

Tags: acoustics, vibrations

I'm studying sound, and speaker isolation solutions specifically. I keep seeing the idea that spikes reduce the transmission of vibration due to the small contact area, but couldn't find any material on how and why this is so, and what frequencies does the decoupling effect work/not work on?

If anyone could give me an explanation, or point me toward the right materials, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Consider the wavelength of sound and the size of 'spikes' on transmission of a given sound wave.

Comment: The most informative article I've read so far says that by having a really small contact area (the tip of a spike/cone), vibrations with long wavelength and high amplitude cannot pass through. Is this accurate, and if so, could anybody please elaborate on it for me?

Answer (score 1):

The general problem of speaker enclosure isolation is one of deliberately creating an *impedance mismatch* between the bottom of the speaker and the floor upon which it sits. The most effective approach is to use the speaker enclosure's own mass in combination with a springy support to prevent the transmission of sound above a certain *cutoff frequency* which in this case is the resonant frequency of the spring/mass system. By making the springs as "soft" as possible, the cutoff can be pushed down to low frequencies.

This principle will be described in detail in any mechanical engineering dynamics textbook that deals with *vibration isolation* or an acoustics text that deals with *soundproofing vibration sources*.